# .Net - Access method 'Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.ListTopicsRequest' failed

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-sdk

See if anybody know what is going on here.

I have a Wrapper around AWSSDK libraries encapsulating some functionality about AWS queues and stuff. This project is on **.Net Framework 4.6.1.** Lets call it **Wrapper**.

The wrapper project consumed as a package by the **Client** project.

Clients on Framework 4.6.1 consuming this project work perfectly. But one of the many consumers is on **.net-core 2.2.**

When this Client on (.net-core) tries to consume the "**Wrapper.Publish**" method (which internally calls **ListTopics**), I get the following exception:

> Attempt by method 'Wrapper.ListEnvironmentTopics()' to access method
>   'Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient.ListTopics(Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.ListTopicsRequest)'
>   failed

All dlls are on the bin folder, all packages are there.

Funny thing is, if I **copy Dlls** directly **from** the **Wrapper** bin folder **into** the **Client** bin folder, all works perfectly.

Any ideas on how to fix this one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Core version of the AWS SDK for .NET does not contain the sync operations like ListTopics. The .NET Core version only has the async operations like `ListTopicsAsync`. This is due to the fact that .NET Core heavily pushes async only and the `HttpClient` used by the SDK only supports async calls.

If you want your wrapper to be portable across both .NET Framework and .NET Core then I recommend using only the async operations.

Comment: I upgraded all the wrapper project to use Async methods, packaged, upgraded client to latest version, and it worked. Thanks Norm !